# Value captured from InputStream not displaying correctly in java

Tags: java, io

Can someone help in understanding below program.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CmdReader {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter age: "); 
            int age = bis.read();

            System.out.println("Hello, you are " + age);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
}
```

output:

```
Enter age: 12
Hello, you are 49
```

Couldn't understand why 49 is printing in place of 12.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

`49` is the ASCII code for the numeral `1`.  Your code is reading in *only the first character*, and assinging it to an `int` uses the value of the character — it doesn't convert it to the number it represents.  You should look into using [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or some other method of parsing values; `BufferedInputStream` only reads data, nothing else.

Comment: Actually, 49 is the value for the first byte read by System.in. Whether it is ASCII (which is most likely is not) depends on the [encoding](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml#table-character-sets-1) of the terminal or whatever is feeding System.in. But, you are correct to recommend using a text library to read text.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i want to know is there any way to convert byte steam value to char stream (Encoding level like StreamEncoder) since BufferedInputStream is byte based stream and System.out is Character based stream. So, it differs in representing data by encoding as Character stream uses Unicode representation. I looked through Charset APIs for changing encoding in java, could not pick up. Correct me if I am wrong. Please suggest Java inbuilt APIs.

Comment: For the above output, what I am expecting is when I enter 1 via byte stream, System.out should print 1 though it is character stream based on the encoding or something like that.

Comment: @Sriram M  maybe *int age = bis.read()-'0'* can meet your requirement.